# How to explain myself in such a situation in a concise way?

Tags: alternatives

The situation as follows:

> Somebody was supposed to contact me by now and they were supposed to guide me to book a room in their guest house, no one one did.

**Question:**

How can I say it in a *concise* way?

---

For example, I tried

> Nobody has contacted me regarding a reservation at the guest house.

But *regarding a reservation* does not sound natural in a way that native speakers would tell it.

Comment: Nobody has contacted me about making a reservation at their guest house.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tend to use `about` often, but it sounds more natural in this case. Thanks; I advise you to turn it into an answer.

Comment: It is my opinion, not a researchable and documentable answer.

Comment: it wasn't supposed to be a researchable answer, so no problem

Comment: @WeatherVane - funny how coders tend to have fun in the language space as well :)

Comment: @MichaelMorgan coders have to be able to turn their hand/mind to other applications too ;)